# IIS - Google plusone button doesn't work

Tags: iis, google-plus-one

Normally I Deploy my websites on servers with Apache ModRewrite using a simple rule in .htaccess to redirect the address with www to without www: `www.example.com => example.com`

**I'm currently deploying a website on a server with Windows using IIS + UrlRewrite**.
In my web.config file where you realize redirection settings I have the following rule to remove the www address:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Via browser, redirection works perfectly!
**But several external tools, such as Facebook and Google+1 button, does not work <strike>when the redirection rule is active</strike>.**

For example, the Google+1 button gives an error to click it (in the requisition click the button I can see the error: "code": -32099, "message": "Backend Error").
Already with Facebook realize the problem when trying to analyze the website with the www address with the following tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
Facebook error: `URL Parsing Error: Error parsing the URL typed, no data was collected.`

<strike>**Disabling the redirection, the Google+1 button and Facebook's analytics tool work perfectly.**</strike>

*Note: the principle does not inform the site because I want to leave a disabled rule to find the solution. If it is necessary to inform the link I will edit this question.*

---

**EDIT:**
After some tests, regardless of the rule enabled or not my problem with the +1 button continues.
I found a thread on Google Code about the same problem, but not understand what should be done:

http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=241

The problem occurs only bound to the site. I created a test page with two +1 buttons, one pointing to the site and pointing to Stackoverflow. By clicking the button Stackoverflow works, but not the other:

http://renalvida.org.br/teste.php